# Excel VBA ADO - Writing to access database - Only first row of recordset written repeatedly

Tags: vba, excel, ado

i have the following code which should take a recordset from an oracle database and write it to an access database.It has about 2000 rows and im expecting to see the same transferred to access. The problem is, only the first row of data is written to the database in an infinite loop! The getconnection function is a custom function that just connects to Access.

What do i need to change to get the code to work? thanks

```
Sub InsertLine(rS As ADODB.recordset)

Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection, adoComm As ADODB.Command

Set adoConn = GetConnection("access")
Set adoComm = New ADODB.Command

With adoComm

    Set .ActiveConnection = adoConn


        Do Until rS.EOF

            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products ([Product], [Category]) " & _
                            "VALUES(?,?)"

            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Value:=rS![ITMDSC], Size:=255)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Value:=rS![GRPDSC], Size:=255)

            .Execute

            rS.MoveNext

            Debug.Print rS![ITMDSC]
        Loop

End With

adoConn.Close
```

End Sub

Thanks for your responses guys. Ive edited the code as follows, but still getting the same issue. Or did i not understand what you meant? sorry im quite new at this. The debug line is showing the correct next record. cheers

```
Sub InsertLine(rS As ADODB.recordset)

Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection, adoComm As ADODB.Command, S As String, S2 As String

Set adoConn = GetConnection("access")
Set adoComm = New ADODB.Command

With adoComm

    Set .ActiveConnection = adoConn

        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products ([Product], [Category]) " & _
                            "VALUES(?,?)"

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Value:=rS![ITMDSC], Size:=255)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Value:=rS![GRPDSC], Size:=255)

        S = rS![ITMDSC]
        S2 = rS![GRPDSC]

        Do Until rS.EOF
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products ([Product], [Category]) " & _
                        "VALUES(S , S2)"

             .Execute
             rS.MoveNext

            Debug.Print rS![ITMDSC]
        Loop

End With

adoConn.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Looks like you're not clearing Parameters in each loop iteration, so just appending additional parameters that are ignored.  You should probably create the two parameters outside the loop, and save a reference to each.  Then in the loop, set the value of the parameters you have already created.

Comment: The problem is that you're recreating the recordset each loop.  move the `CommandText` through `Execute` lines outside of the loop.

Comment: Are you trying to add new records to the table or add fields to an existing record?

Comment: I'm trying to add new records to the table

Answer (score -1):

Why use a parameter query? it's making it overcomplicated...

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products ([Product], [Category]) " & _
               "VALUES('" & rS![ITMDSC] & "','" & rS![GRPDSC] & "')"
.Execute
 rS.MoveNext
```

if you do want to use a parameter query, then a

```
.Parameters.Refresh
```

should clear out current parameters

Comment: "Why use a parameter query?" - never heard of SQL injection?  In any case this won't work as you have no quotes around the varchar parameters.  -1

Comment: @joe, 1. quotes are minor - added them into the example.  2. If you are worried about injection, parse/sanitize the input before placing the values into the string.